# Change hostname on SSH session

Tags: linux, ubuntu

When I SSH into my server, it has a really long name

```
user@this-is-a-really-really-really-really-long-server-name:~$
```

How can I change this to

```
user@short-name:~$
```

I'm not sure what to even google for.

Comment: Do you want to change the server's hostname, or just display something shorter?

Comment: make the display shorter.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3012/changing-the-bash-prompt

Comment: Put that as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks Matt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Matt said. There is similar question on [Unix.stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3012/changing-the-bash-prompt)

And you find some Background
[here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html)

Modify PS11

```
PS1="touch me : "
```

Answer (score 1):

question is if you want to really change the hostname of the server, or only whats displayed at the beginning of the cli.

if you want to change the hostname, you better check specifically for your distribution.

if you only want to change what's displayed at the beginning of the cli, alter the ${PS1} variable via ~/.bashrc (user specific) or /etc/profile (global) or something like that.